# The way to ask regarding UI design

Tags: discussion

A couple of days ago, I have asked to evaluate the new UI design of the search bar that I see in the new Firefox, https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/46591 I believe that UX is exactly intended for this purpose: to figure out how good UI elements must look and evaluate concrete applications with respect to them. Instead of response, I have got the downvotes and explanation that this discusses a concrete app and therefore must be migrated to superuser (where it will be closed as no question because I do not have any question regarding how to use the Firefox).

I have responded this to the comments, altogether with the remark that this is outrageous to decide for me what I want to discuss and that very fact that I ask here implies that I am interested in the design principle and it is unetical (it does not improve my user experience) to imply any other (bad) intent from my side. Instead of correcting their position, my clarification was removed! Some special group within UX community has decided that they know better my intent and will dictate me (and to the world) what my intent is and I must agree that my intent is unacceptable. How is this possible? How can others people dictate me what I want to discuss? Shouldn't OP decide that? If they do not want to discuss the find bar design principle then why do they attribute this reluctance to me?

For comparison, [here they ask about improving checkboxes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/48491). I want to respond the way others responded to my question: UX is not for discussing particular applications, it is for discussing general design principles. It is out-of the scope and must be downvoted. Why is the public reaction is opposite to mine question?

Answer (score 3):

The reason your comments were deleted is because they were not constructive and did not add to the discussion of the question. You suggested that people downvoting your question and debating whether it belonged on the site was intended as an attack on your character. It was not, and changing the discussion from being about the question to being about your character is not constructive.

I suggest you return to your question and try to improve it so that people feel they can answer it or help you out. Right now, it seems that the question is unfit for our site because it asks an unanswerable question.

Comment: I do not undrestand which post are you talking about. My complaint was not my character but disregarding the character/purpose of my post. Why do people tell me that it is not about design principle? Why do they avoid discussing the design principle of such a bar?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask the people in the comments to clarify why they don't feel your question is useful and go from there?

Comment: I asked there, clarified my post but my comments were deleted. I cannot be constructive if my comments are deleted. Ok?